# Checkbox CSS glow color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way to change/force checkbox glow color on focus?

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the css **:focus** property of *checkbox*:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:focus {
  outline-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```